# Swift CollectionView didSelectItemAt no longer working after overriding touch in cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I wanted to have a `tapAnimation` on my `CustomCollectionViewCell` so I added these lines inside the `class`:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
        self.theView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
        self.theView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
        self.theView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
    }
}
```

`theView` is pretty much the whole `cell` here. However after adding this, my `didSelectItemAt` in my `collectionView` is no longer firing. Any idea what I am doing wrong here? It works without the `override`-snippets.

To add: I would actually like to have a animation like in the App-Store (only the tap animation, not transition!)

If you need any more info just let me know!

Answer (score 0):

- You forgot to call `super` when overriding.

Ex:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    ....
```